# UpdatePipeline (SelfMutate) stage gone missing from my AWS CDK pipeline

Tags: github, aws-cdk

I've been trying to fix an issue with our CDK pipeline. The pipeline was failing at the UpdatePipeline stage, while trying to perform the SelfMutate action. It turned out that we had recently made a change in the pipeline code to use a secret corresponding to the personal access token from a different github account.  This new account did not have access to the repo containing the pipeline code. Once the account was given access, the pipeline was able to run successfully.

However, while trying to diagnose the problem, I temporarily pushed a change to add `selfMutating: false` to the CDK pipeline. At first, the pipeline continued trying to run the SelfMutate action (maybe because the github access issue meant it couldn't see this change). Once I resolved the access problem, the pipeline ran successfully and removed the UpdatePipeline stage altogether.

I then reverted my change, thinking that UpdatePipeline and SelfMutate would be reinstated. However this has not happened, and the pipeline is now running with this stage being missed out altogether.

Why has this happened and what can I do to reinstate self-mutation?

Comment: A pipeline with `selfMutating: false` will not self-mutate, so it doesn't have a way to "reinstate" anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turned off self mutation then subsequent deploys will not affect the pipeline.

To fix this you need to enable self mutation and deploy the pipeline stack manually from you machine to update.